# Version devel while setting up horizon in local

Tags: horizon

I am trying to build horizon in local by following https://github.com/stellar/go/blob/master/services/horizon/internal/docs/admin.md

The setup is complete. When I do horizon version it say devel. Why?

Why not the latest 10.2.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version string can be set when building the app, but it's not determined automatically and it [defaults to `devel`](https://github.com/stellar/go/blob/69e628cf1cef67bbea02abc2e53ad3cddb60e4e8/support/app/main.go#L33). SDF surely has some kind of build tool/script that performs that for their release builds.

If you want to set the version string for your own builds, here is how to specify the build params:

```
root@stellar2:~# go build -ldflags "-X github.com/stellar/go/support/app.version=MyOwn-0.15.3" github.com/stellar/go/services/horizon
root@stellar2:~# ./horizon version
MyOwn-0.15.3
root@stellar2:~#
```

If you checkout master you'll in fact have the latest development version, if you want a [specific release](https://github.com/stellar/go/tags) you have to check that out first `git checkout tags/horizon-v0.15.3`.

Comment: even after checking out horizon-v0.16.0  (using git checkout tags/horizon-v0.16.0) and starting , still getting version devel

Comment: Also to build I am using following command : go install github.com/stellar/go/services/horizon. I executed the command given by u " go build -ldflags "-X github.com/stellar/go/support/app.version=MyOwn-0.15.3" github.com/stellar/go/services/horizon" before the go install but still getting the version as devel

Comment: 1) the version is not set in the repository at all, it is only set when building 2) do `go install -ldflags "-X github.com/stellar/go/support/app.version=MyOwn-0.15.3` in a single step (go build=compile and save binary in curent folder; go install=compile and save binary in $GOPATH/bin )

Comment: How do we set version  for core?

Comment: the stellar-core make script determines it automatically from the git status (it's then replaced in src/main/StellarCoreVersion.cpp.in)